# TorBirdy: Doesn't find keys on preconfigured onion keyserver

Tags: onion-services, email, torbirdy

I use Icedove/Thunderbird together with TorBirdy. And now it doesn't find any keys anymore on the preconfigured keyserver: hkp://2eghzlv2wwcq7u7y.onion. I have no idea how to deal with this. Any suggestions where to start looking? Tor is working fine, I can also send emails ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that this keyserver is offline.

At least downloading [my key from the hidden service](http://2eghzlv2wwcq7u7y.onion:11371/pks/lookup?search=weasel%40debian.org&op=index) fails even without TorBirdy.

Comment: I just tried it again and the key server is online:

http://2eghzlv2wwcq7u7y.onion:11371/pks/lookup?search=weasel%40debian.org&op=index

But still in IceWeasel/Thunderbird a request to the keyserver returns nothing. Also with other keyserver, that can be reached over Tor.